# Disable `<h:commandButton>` after clicked, but action should be fired

Tags: javascript, jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a `<h:commandButton>` in my XHTML page. I want the button to be disabled as soon as I click the button. Then the button should call the action. My button gets disabled as I expect but the problem is that the action is not fired. 

`<h:commandButton value="Go" onclick="this.disabled=true" action="#{bean.go()}"/>`

But if I remove the `onclick` attribute the action is fired.

Or if I used an `<a4j:commandButton>` it works. 
Following a4j button works.

`<a4j:commandButton value="Go" onclick="this.disabled=true" action="#{bean.go()}"/>`

How can I disable a `<h:commandButton>` after being clicked, so that the action still fires?

Comment: check this stack answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2594864/1358004

Comment: @ViralShah : I want the button to be disabled after clicked once on it. Is your solution still applicable? You meant `onclick="this.disabled = 'disable'"`? It also doesn't work. :(

Comment: Why don't you set some arbitrary value as `false` when the button is clicked? But before just setting the value, you should first check for this value being `true` before proceeding. That way, it may not look disabled, but will technically be disabled.

Comment: @ianpgall : Good idea. The problem is the button still looks enabled.

Comment: If you use the `<a4j:commandButton>`, you can use the `oncomplete` javascript method that executes after the action is performed: `<a4j:commandButton value="Go" onclick="this.disabled=true" action="#{bean.go()}" oncomplete="this.disabled=true" />`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The `oncomplete` feature has nothing to do with this - the problem is before the AJAX event even gets fired, and is prevented because the button is disabled because of the `onclick` code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` , that way the action will be fired and the button will be disabled...

```
<h:commandButton value="Go"
   onclick="setTimeout('this.disabled = true;', 50);" 
   action="#{bean.go()}"/>
```

You can also take a look at the following question too :[How can I disable an h:commandButton without preventing the action and actionListener from being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11744597/617373)

Comment: Nice idea. Can it be called as a 'hack'? It worked well.I used it as `setTimeout('this.disabled = true', 50);`. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome , I guess that yes... Looks like a *hack/workaround* to me too...