# JSF 2.0 command button to prevent multiple submission using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 and dealing with the multiple submission when click double-clicked on the submit button.

I have used jQuery to disable a command button when click,
and here is my code:

```
$("input[name='form:submitButton']").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    return true;
});
```

When I click on the button, the submit button disable successfully but the submission does not fire at all.

Anyone could give me some hints on it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Are you sure the selector is working? What does `alert('xx: ' + $("input[name='form:submitButton']").length)` print?

Comment: My guess is you have an error in your page as your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/N7n7X/. Check the console for errors

Comment: I have just checked.
The selector is working and no error has been captured on the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13117136/617373

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("input[name='form:submitButton']").click(function() {
    setTimeout("$(this).attr('disabled', true);", 50);
    return true;
});
```

or

```
<h:commandButton value="Go"
   onclick="setTimeout('this.disabled = true;', 50);" 
   action="#{bean.go()}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById(\'' + this.id + '\').disabled=true;">
  <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{bean.listener}"/> 
</h:commandButton>
```

You can add to `f:ajax  oncomplete="....disabled=false"`, or update the whole view to re-enable the button.