# JSF commandlink and form submit Google Analytics event tracking

Tags: javascript, forms, jsf, google-analytics

I am trying to get, first, a h:commandLink to send off a custom _trackEvent to our analytics profile.

```
<h:commandLink id="clDisplayDoc" action="#{displayDocManagedBean.displayDocument}" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'practitionerDocs', 'download']);">
```

This isn't working as I suspect the event is being canceled by a page refresh or submission.

Secondly, I would like a form submission to send a custom event.

```
<h:form id="practitionerForm" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Submit', 'Provide Feedback']);">
```

This isn't working either. Is there a way to ensure both events get sent off correctly?

Comment: In order to get better answers, it's better if you present your code in plain HTML instead of as raw JSF. JavaScript doesn't interact on JSF code, but instead on its generated HTML output. As to your concrete problem, the `_gaq` is asynchronous, not synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jsf, but for the first event I think your running into a race condition. Try setting a timeout to give the event enough time to send - [Disable `<h:commandButton>` after clicked, but action should be fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116890/disable-hcommandbutton-after-clicked-but-action-should-be-fired)

Comment: The `<h:commandLink>` just generates a HTML `<a>` element which submits a parent `<form method="post">` element. The `<h:form>` just generates a `<form method="post">` element. Ultimately, JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code producer and therefore irrelevant to the concrete problem. The OP only doesn't seem to fully realize that.